# Gateaux differentiable

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and Lebesgue measurable respect to $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^n$, for any $p\in [1,\infty)$, let
$$ f(u) = \int_E |u|^p\;d\mu\qquad \;\forall\; u\in L^p(E, \mathbb{R})$$
Show that $f$ is Gateaux differentiable over $L^p(E)$, that is the following limit exist for any $e\in L^p(E,\mathbb{R})$
$$\lim_{t\longrightarrow \infty} \frac{f(u+te) - f(u)}{t}$$

For each $x\in L^p(E)$, let $g_x(s) = |a(x)+ stb(x)|$ where $s\in [0,1]$ and
Using the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, I set a sequence of function
$$g_n = \frac{|a+t_nb|^p - |a|^p}{t_n}$$
where $t_n \longrightarrow 0$ when $n\longrightarrow \infty$, note that we can choose $n$ is  large such that $a+t_nb$ and $a$ is negative or positive together , so I cant find the limit
$$\lim_{n\longrightarrow \infty} g_n =\lim_{n\longrightarrow \infty} \frac{ g'(c)}{t_n} = p|a(x) + ct_nb(x)|^{p-1}b(x) = p|a(x)|^{p-1}b(x)$$ 
for some $c\in (0,1)$, so for each $x\in L^p(E)$ we can find a $n_x\in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$ |f_n(x)| \leq |p|a(x)|^{p-1}b(x)|\qquad \forall\; n\geq n_x$$
but how I can't remove the respect of $n$ to $x$ in order to using the  Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the claim is not correct for $p=1$. Consider for example $E=[0,1]$, $u:=0$ and $e:=1$. Then it can be easily seen from the definition that

$$\frac{f(u+t e)-f(u)}{t} = \frac{|t|}{t},$$

and therefore the limit $$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(u+te)-f(u)}{t}$$ does not exist.

Now suppose that $p>1$. Set $$\varphi(t) :=|u(x)+te(x)|^p$$ for fixed $x \in E$. As $p>1$, we have

$$\begin{align*} |\varphi'(t)|  &= p \cdot |u(x)+t \cdot e(x)|^{p-1} \cdot |e(x)| \\ &\leq p \cdot \big( |u(x)|+|e(x)| \big)^{p-1} \cdot |e(x)| =: w(x) \end{align*}$$

for any $t \leq 1$. By Hölder's inequality, $w \in L^p(E)$. By the mean value theorem, we conclude

$$\frac{|u(x)+t e(x)|^p-|u(x)|^p}{t} = \frac{\varphi(t)-\varphi(0)}{t} = |\varphi'(\xi)| \leq |w(x)|$$

for some intermediate value $\xi=\xi(t,x)$. Since $w \in L^p$, we can apply the dominated convergence theorem and find

$$\begin{align*} \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(u+t e)-f(u)}{t} &= \lim_{t \to 0} \int \frac{|u(x)+t e(x)|^p-|u(x)|^p}{t} \, dx \\ &= p \int |u(x)|^{p-1} \cdot e(x) \cdot \text{sgn}(u(x)) \, dx \end{align*}$$

Comment: it's not true for $p>1$, since the function $x\longmapsto |x|$ is not differentible when $x = 0$

Comment: @user93736 You mean for $p=1$...? For $p>1$ the function $x \mapsto |x|^p$ is differentiable.